# What does cookie opt-out mean in the context of the EU Cookie Law?

Tags: eu-cookie-law

The site of [Cookie Consent](https://cookieconsent.insites.com/) tells me that in Germany, I need to offer an opt-out on cookies.

That, however, is impossible, as any decision made by the visitor has to be recorded in a cookie or it's lost on the next request.

So what does this mean? Is Cookie Consent wrong about the requirement, is the requirement inherently nonsensical or did I overlook something here?

Comment: Why don't you ask them at the cookie consent site?

Comment: They have no contact form.

Comment: What? This sounds like a typical government inspired solution with no way to win. A real Catch 22! Good luck. I have no ideas. Cheers!!

Comment: @John and you trust them despite being not able to contact them?  I wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Some types of cookies including user input cookies which are valid for the duration of the session are exempt from the cookie consent law. What this means is that you may use a cookie to identify if cookies have been consented to or not for the duration of the session for the user.

Source: [European Commission's Information Providers Guide](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm)